# React Webpack render error

Tags: reactjs, webpack, babeljs

I am new to react and I am trying to follow the course on lynda

> React.js Essential Training it

it seems that tutorial are little outdated so as I was following I run in to the following error, while trying to compile I got this error [image]

my webpackconfig

```
var webpack = require("webpack");

module.exports = {
    entry:  __dirname + "/src/index.js",
    output: {
        path: __dirname + "/dist/assets",
        filename: "bundle.js",
        publicPath: "assets"
    },
    devServer: {
        inline: true,
        contentBase: __dirname + "/dist",
        port: 3000
    },
    module: {
      rules: [
    {
    test: /\.js$/,
    loader: ["babel-loader"],
    }
    ]
    }
}
```

and js file

```
const { render } = ReactDOM

render(
    <h1 id='title'
        className='header'
        style={{backgroundColor: 'orange', color: 'white', fontFamily: 'verdana'}}>
    Hello World
    </h1>,
    document.getElementById('react-container')
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your problem here is that you don't use the [react preset](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-preset-react) of babel:

Don't forget to install it first: `npm install babel-preset-react`

Answer (score 2):

Update your webpack config with this

```
var webpack = require("webpack");

module.exports = {
    entry: __dirname + "/src/index.js",
    output: {
        path: __dirname + "/dist/assets",
        filename: "bundle.js",
        publicPath: "assets"
    },
    devServer: {
        inline: true,
        contentBase: __dirname + "/dist",
        port: 3000
    },
    module: {
        rules: [{
            test: /\.js$/,
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
            query: {
                presets: ['react']
            }
        }]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to install babel-preset-react and babel-preset-es2015 :

```
npm install --save-dev babel-preset-react babel-preset-es2015
```

and include this in your package.json:

```
"babel": {
    "presets": [
      "es2015",
      "react"
    ]
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

you have to use `react` and `es2015` presets for babel-loader.
you can create separate `.babelrc` file or you can set in `webpack.config.js`

https://www.twilio.com/blog/2015/08/setting-up-react-for-es6-with-webpack-and-babel-2.html

Answer (score 1):

Where is your return() statement in render() ???
You need to return jsx.